# How to create a feel of urgency while showing remaining time (in days) on a WebUI ?

Tags: website-design, web, ux-designer

I'm creating a site where I have different products for sale. For many products, the sale get closed after a certain amount of time(like after a week). I want to put some kind of indicator with 'remaining days' which create a sense of urgency in mind of user. Should I use Red color with simple text or should I use some Icon ? Need suggesstions to get it done in a nice way. 
I'll be really thankfull for your valuable suggesstions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps a stopwatch icon with the time counting down under....
It could actually change colors from green to yellow to red as the sale is winding down. 
If you want a minimalist approach you can simply use text such as : sale ends in 00:31 mins (for example ) 
Any of the above methods will do, no reason to overcomplicate the interface.

Comment: I like @Stanley's answer, with a few tweaks: 
Iconography works great, but if you want to give a bigger sense of urgency, it's going to need that combined with the colours you mentioned and, most of all, a second/minute counter. 

As the offer approaches the deadline, it should be translated into hotter colours, e.g.: from Black to Yellow to Red. And the counter should follow: from Days remaining to hours remaining (with the counter downt o the minute - 24h 21 min) to minutes (down to the second/milisecond - 59 min 40 sec)

Comment: Thanks @Stanley , putting stopwatch icon is actually a good option with changing colors.

Comment: No problem Omar! hope it works out well.